# Why are my services not showing up on the network after started in docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm-mode

After fiddling around for a couple days with what was new to me a week ago, I'm kind of stuck and would like your help. I've created a docker swarm with some Pi's running Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS and when I use the command:

```
$ docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.visualizer.yml visualizer
```

The terminal feedback is:

```
Creating network visualizer_default
Creating service visualizer_visualizersvc
```

Practically the same output when I run:

```
$ docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.home-assistant.yml home-assistant
```

Checking the stacks:

```
$ docker stack ls
NAME                SERVICES            ORCHESTRATOR
home-assistant      1                   Swarm
visualizer          1                   Swarm
```

Checking services in stacks:

```
$ docker stack services visualizer
ID                  NAME                       MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                             PORTS
t5nz28hzbzma        visualizer_visualizersvc   replicated          0/1                 dockersamples/visualizer:latest   *:8000->8080/tcp
$ docker stack services home-assistant
ID                  NAME                           MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                 PORTS
olj1nbx5vj40        home-assistant_homeassistant   replicated          0/1                 homeassistant/home-assistant:stable   *:8123->8123/tcp
```

When I then browse to the ports specified in `docker-compose.visualizer.yml` or `docker-compose.home-assistant.yml` there is no response on the server side ("can't connect"). Identical for both the manager and worker IP. This is inside a home network, in a single subnet with no traffic rules set for LAN traffic.

EDIT: a portscan reveals no open ports in the specified range on either host.

Any comments on my work are welcome as I'm learning, but I would very much like to see some containers 'operational'.

As a reference I included the `docker-compose` files:

**docker-compose.home-assistant.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  homeassistant:
    image: homeassistant/home-assistant:stable
    ports:
      - "8123:8123"
    volumes:
      - './home-assistant:/config'
    environment:
      TZ: 'Madrid'
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host
```

**docker-compose.visualizer.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  visualizersvc:
    image: alexellis2/visualizer-arm:latest
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - 'node.role==manager'
    ports:
      - '8000:8080'
    volumes:
        - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

*Bonus points for telling me if I should always approach the manager through the specified ports or if I have to approach the machine running the service (or any good documentation on the subject.)*

Answer (score 0):

*Not long after you post a question you happen to find the answer yourself of course:*

**I never scaled the services** (to 1 in my case)

```
docker service scale [SERVICE_ID]=1
```

EDIT: The services were not scaling to 1 because of another error, I think in the visualizer, but this brought me to the final answer.

Now I'm getting a mountain of new error messages, but at least those are verbose :)

Any feedback is still welcome.